# vbox layout is not working in border layout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a requirment where i need to put one item inside `vbox` layout. my item is having a border layout and `west` and `center` reason having some `vbox` layout componet. below I am putting the code of item. In this main panel is border layout and reason having `vbox` but this is not working.

my Code :

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: 'Border Layout',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'South Region is resizable',
        region: 'south',     // position for region
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 100,
        layout : 'fit',
        split: true,// enable resizing
        margin: '0 5 5 5'
    },{
        // xtype: 'panel' implied by default
        title: 'West Region is collapsible',
        region:'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        margin: '5 0 0 5',
        width: 100,
        layout: 'vbox',
        height: 200,
        items:[{
            title: 'South Region is resizable',
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100
            },{
            title: 'ss Region is resizable2',
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100
        }],
        collapsible: true,   // make collapsible
        id: 'west-region-container',

    },{
        title: 'Center Region',
        region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
        xtype: 'panel',
        width : 300,
        layout: 'vbox',
        margin: '5 5 0 0',
        items:[{
                title: 'South Region is resizable',
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 50,

        },
            {
                title: 'ss Region is resizable',
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 10
            }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Below is my Actual code where I am using `vbox`Layout and then `border` layout is one of the item of this. I am getting Layout run failed error

```
Ext.define('myApp.myData.myApp', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.myApp',
    controller: 'myAppController',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        margin: '5 10 0 0',
        height: 28
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        itemId: 'mainPanel',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        defaults: {
            margin: '3 10 2 5'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'myPanel'
            },{
                xtype : 'panel',
                height: 500,
                width : 300,
                layout: 'border',
                items :[{
                    xtype : 'panel',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: "stretch"
                    },
                    items :[{
                        xtype: 'myPanel1'
                    },{
                        xtype : 'myPanel2'
                    }]
                },{
                    xtype : 'panel',
                    layout: {
                           type: "vbox",
                           align: "stretch"
                        },
                    items :[{
                        xtype: 'myGrid'
                    }]
                }]
            } 
        ]
    }]
});
```

Any help will appriciate.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `layout` to:

```
layout: {
   type: "vbox",
   align: "stretch"
}
```

And put `flex` on child items:

```
flex: 1
```

Comment: flex in the sense. to seperate the vbox items ?

Comment: `flex` is how much of `height` in `vbox layout` is for each child.

Comment: This is working fine in fiddler. but in my code in myApp i am getting `Layout run fail` error. I will put actual code if you want.

Comment: that would be great

Comment: you did not define `region` for child items is `border layout`. `center` is required

Comment: Nope that i missed accedently. still getting same error.